# Iterating through QButtonGroup::buttons causes a crash

Tags: c++, loops, qt, iterator, qbuttongroup

This is my symbol definition:

```
auto box1=new QCheckBox;
box1->setText("choice1");
auto box2=new QCheckBox;
box2->setText("choice2")
QPushButton* button=new QPushButton;
connect(button,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Widget::onClicked);
auto group=new QButtonGroup;
group->setExclusive(false);
group->addButton(box1);
group->addButton(box2);
```

```
void Widget::onClicked()
{
    std::for_each(group->buttons().begin(),group->buttons().end(),[](QAbstractButton* button){
            button->setChecked(!button->isChecked());
    });
    /*
    QList<QAbstractButton *> buttons=group->buttons();
    std::for_each(buttons.begin(),buttons.end(),[](QAbstract* button){
    button->setChecked(!button->isChecked());
    });
    */
}
```

The `buttons()` call will return a `QList<QAbstractButton *>`.

I tried to use `onClicked` slot to iterate though the list and do something.

If I add the uncommented section of code, the program crashes. I debugged it and found out that it looped three times, but only two elements were actually added, and the third loop will crash the program.

And if I remove the commented out piece of code, it works.

I want to know why the first way of writing, that is, the code that is not commented out, will cause an error.

Comment: I do not see an iterator being returned anywhere (as per question title), nor do I see `QList<QAbstractButton *` being returned either... And you seem to say "*I write it in another way and it work.*"...... So what is the problem you are trying to solve? On another note, why not do: `connect(button, &QAbstractButton::clicked; box1, &QAbstractButton::toggle);` (repeat for `box2`)?

Comment: @Atmo I'm just giving an example. If there are too many buttons, I should use this way of writing

Comment: @Atmo There was something wrong with my title, I changed it

Comment: If there are too many buttons (I guess you mean checkboxes), you still should make individual connections to each... My guess as to why it does not work (I have not checked), is that `std::for_each(group->buttons().begin(), group->buttons().end(), [...])` creates 2 copies of a list, the iterators of which do not match (it is effectively doing `std::for_each(list1.begin(), list2.end(), [...])` and you cannot reach the `end` iterator of one list from the `begin` iterator of another.

Comment: @Atmo Thank you, I seem to understand a little bit

Comment: As Atmo says, you're getting two different iterators, because each call to `buttons()` creates a different list: it doesn't matter if their contents are identical, the iterator must belong to the *same* list. Either get the button list before entering the loop (as you did in the commented code), or use a while loop with the iterator returned by `begin()`.

Comment: @Atmo Can you upvote for my post again? thank you

Comment: You corrected your question so that's fair enough

Comment: @air note that the main purpose of QButtonGroup is to logically group button widgets so that they can be made mutually exclusive, be mapped to specific ids, or provide common signals that would be triggered whenever any button in the group is activated. If you only need to simplify signal connections or iterations, then just use a simple list.

Comment: @musicamante: I do agree a simple list is more suited than a button group for the usage you describe but on that note, I replied to the comment you left on my answer below. Let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in comments (not checked myself but confirmed by @musicamente), `std::for_each(group->buttons().begin(), group->buttons().end(), [...])` creates 2 separate lists (by copy construction), the `end()` iterator of which are different; importantly, you cannot reach the `end()` iterator of the latter from the `begin()` iterator of the former, which causes `std::for_each` to keep looping past the end.

This issue would not have occurred with a range-based loop (which is easier to read to top). While I am at it, I will use the `toggle` method to switch the checkstate of checkboxes:

```cpp
void Widget::onClicked()
{
    for (auto checkbox: group->buttons())
        button->toggle();
}
```

On a separate note, unless you have a specific reason to do it the way you present in your question,such as @musicamente's comment below (but even then, I had rather create a connection every time I create a new checkbox at run-time + disconnection is automatic when objects are deleted), the correct way of connecting your button to your many checkboxes would be:

```cpp
[...]
QPushButton* button=new QPushButton;
auto group=new QButtonGroup;
group->setExclusive(false);
group->addButton(box1);
group->addButton(box2);
for (auto checkbox : group->buttons())
    QObject::connect(button, &QAbstractButton::clicked, checkbox, &QAbstractButton::toggle);
```

This saves declaring `void Widget::onClicked()`.

Depending on the rest of the `Widget` class, it could even work without `group`, in that fashion:

```cpp
[...]
QPushButton* button=new QPushButton;
for (auto checkbox : findChildren<QCheckBox>(QString()))
    QObject::connect(button, &QAbstractButton::clicked, checkbox, &QAbstractButton::toggle);
```

Comment: The benefit of using a function that internally iterates through the button group is that it allows dynamic groups: buttons can be added (or removed) at run time while making the function consistent for any member of that group. It isn't clear from the OP if the purpose of the group is just to have a list of buttons that is easily iterable, though, but the concept remains.

Comment: I guess you can do it that way but personally, I has still rather have 2 lines (checkbox creation + the connection) rather than just 1 line but have a whole slot be declared. Even worse in that regard when using a simple list: it makes it 1 line for the creation, 1 line to add to the list, 1 slot to declare, the list declaration + consume memory to store it + all the code to clean the list when a checkbox needs to be removed.... In short, a lot of trouble that multiple individual connections avoid.

Comment: About your note on my comment, I wasn't specifically referring to button creation and deletion: a button could be added to the group even if it already existed, or removed even without deleting it (for instance, to move the button to another group). While it would be still possible to manually disconnect the signal to "remove" the checkbox from the group, removing it from the list/group would certainly be simpler, not to mention that further disconnections or reconnections can be done with a single call, instead of iterating through the group every time.

Comment: "consume memory to store it": you don't think that a QButtonGroup (which is a full QObject instance) requires less memory than a list, do you? ;-)

Comment: I meant: you have a simple list instead of a QButtonGroup but with connections, you need neither. So what I am comparing is no list at all vs a QList.

Comment: You need neither only if the target widgets are all the widgets of that type within that parent (using `findChildren()`). If there are *other* similar widgets within the same UI, then you need one of those "groupings": a list would be simpler if the main features of QButtonGroup are not required (common signals, etc), but there would be nothing wrong in using it even if technically it's not its main purpose. Obviously, every case is different, but having individual connections (having the same purpose) may not be always the good choice, especially if you need further disconnections.

Comment: We don't understand each other :-) In the context of my **comment** (not my answer) following yours, my point was to connect the checkboxes right after they get created: doing so makes code shorter. You don't need to use `findChildren()` to mass connect everything if you proceed that way and in fact, you need no list at all, including removal of checkbox. Deletion will auto-disconnect the signal + as long as you have a variable pointing to a checkbox you want to disconnect, there is no need to look up for it in a list (= 1 more unnecessary line of code) since `disconnect` will work just fine.